# Nuvola Player not working with Google Play Music

Tags: gnome, streaming, music-player

I installed Nuvola Player from its stable PPA repo. I can open it, sign in to Google Play and view my library etc. But once I try to play a track, the loading image (rotating arrow) appears and it stays like that forever (have to close the program).

My machine is running Ubuntu GNOME 13.04.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I also had this problem, just tried it again and now it seems to work. have you tried recently?